# Density plot of integral. TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, numpy, physics

So I am trying to get this density plot to work for the given integral. Not sure what I am missing but I am getting this error.

> Traceback:
>
> runfile('F:/PHY 281/Homework/Set 4/tyest3.py', wdir='F:/PHY
>   281/Homework/Set 4') Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('F:/PHY 281/Homework/Set 4/tyest3.py', wdir='F:/PHY 281/Homework/Set 4')
>
> File
>   "E:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 710, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "E:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 101, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "F:/PHY 281/Homework/Set 4/tyest3.py", line 27, in 
>       gb = quad(Jm,0,1e-6) [0]
>
> File
>   "E:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py",
>   line 323, in quad
>       points)
>
> File
>   "E:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py",
>   line 388, in _quad
>       return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
>
> TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import cos,sin,pi




lmda = 5e-7
m = 1
def Jm(thta):
    return (1/pi)*cos(m*thta-x*sin(thta))



xvals = np.linspace(-10*lmda,10*lmda,200)
zvals = np.linspace(-20*lmda,20*lmda,200)
x,z = np.meshgrid(xvals,zvals)

gb = quad(Jm,0,1e-6) [0]



plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.imshow(gb,origin='lower',extent=[-10*lmda,10*lmda,-20*lmda,20*lmda])
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('V/m')
cbar.ax.set_xlabel('E')
plt.xlabel('x nm')
plt.ylabel('y nm')


plt.show()
```

Comment: I think the problem is with `x*sin(thta)` in `Jm` function. You aware that `x` is 2D array with a shape of 200x200?

Comment: so should I do a separate linspace within Jm for x?

Comment: I'm not sure. Can you provide the equation that you are trying to solve?

Comment: The equation is there in the defined function. It is the return. It's a Bessel function

Comment: Ok. Understood. See this post: [How to evaluate single integrals of multivariate functions with Python's scipy.integrate.quad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099892/how-to-evaluate-single-integrals-of-multivariate-functions-with-pythons-scipy-i). In order to make it work you will need to pass additional parameter `args` to `scipy.integrate.quad`. The problem is that you can only pass one value, not an array (`x` in your case).

Comment: Solution for this could be making a loop, like here: [Passing variable from an array to scipy.integrate.quad() in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728528/passing-variable-from-an-array-to-scipy-integrate-quad-in-python). Another thing you could probably do is to use SymPy to calculate the integral symbolically and supply array `x` to it at once, which should be more efficient.